# Google Embedded maps api link not working with Phonegap in android devices

Tags: cordova, google-maps, iframe, phonegap-build, google-maps-embed

I have build an app and using the above iframe for the google maps

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d53529.11460374677!2d74.9441465!3d33.0151193!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xa04ab611af048191!2sVaishno+Devi!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1386967847922" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe></div>
```

But it is not working on android phone

On Browser it is perfectly working. Can someone help with this. I am  new to this

Comment: [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Answer (score 2):

I succeeded to make it work by adding

```
<allow-navigation href="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/*" />
```

entry in my config.xml.

Also, note that you will require a key (Android key in your case for android) if you want google maps embed to work correctly.